# Class inheritance with constructor create with dependency injection

Tags: c#

I have class with constructor with Dependency Injection.

```
public abstract class example : ApiController
    {
        readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
          
        public example(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
    }
```

Then I try to inherit from it.

```
public class test : example
    {
        readonly IService _service;

        public test(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
    }
```

I have error with message: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter httpcontextaccesor...".
Thanks for helps.

Comment: So how are you satisfying example's constructor with test's constructor?

Comment: dependency injection isn't really relevant. To create a `test`, which is an `example`, you need to give it an `IHttpContextAccessor` so that it can pass it to it's parent class' constructor.

Comment: `public test(IService service, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(httpContextAccessor)`?

Comment: Your test constructor will have to call a constructor on the example class, which means you will have to pass something to that constructor. Something like `public test(IService service, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(httpContextAccessor) { ... }`